# Is it possible to create virual hub for PPTP clients?

Tags: vpn, pptp

There is a Linux machine (`A`) running pptpd inside a university network behind a firewall but with real IP. I have no access or any knowledge of IP distribution in this network, so I can't just set `remoteip X.Y.Z.200-250` in pptpd config, since it might cause conflicts. I wonder whether it is possible to create a virtual hub for all connected VPN clients, which is then NATed to the real network.

Here is some clumpsy ascii grpaphics illustrating what I want to achieve:

```
PPTP-client  ---\  ________________     ________________________
                 \ |   10.0.0.0/24 |    |10.0.0.0/24     real ip|
PPTP-client  ----->| Virt. hub (A) |----|ethX       A       eth0|----- Outside world
                 / |_______________|    |_______________________|
PPTP-client  ---/
```

Googling shows that PacketiX.NET and UT-VPN have such built-in capabilities, but I have no idea of how to do it with ordinary pptpd. I've tried creating dummy interface, configuring it with static IP and then giving to pptp-client the IPs from this interface subnet, but with no success.

Usage of other vpn-servers is problematic since quite paranoid firewall settings and me having to use wetware ssh server for any operations on `A`.

Comment: It seems like it should be possible.  I am somewhat confused about the choice of PPTP when getting through a firewalls is a concern.  I find that OpenVPN is far easier to get through a firewall, particularly on a Linux server.  On Linux it pretty easy to setup OpenVPN to accept connections on any one of many ports, OpenVPN can even operate through an http proxy.  Setting up a special IP range for OpenVPN is also simple.

Comment: @Zoredache Sorry for late feedback -- there were blackout out there, so there were no possibility to try OpenVPN. Now I've managed to do so, and it works like a charm! Could you repost your comment as an answer, so I will mark it 'Accepted'?

Answer (score 0):

You could use PPTPd server (if GRE proto is not filtered by your network).
PPTD will create new ppp interface for each client on your server.

For example you specify

```
localip 192.168.101.1-100
remoteip 192.168.101.101-200
```

So every ppp* interface will obtain new IP from 192.168.101 subnet.
Finally, you could NAT all traffic from this subnet to you real IP 
(dont forget about net.ipv4.ip_forward=1)

```
# here could be full MASQUERADE or SNAT 
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o real_interface0 -j MASQUERADE
# forward for all ppp + MSS tune,  conntrack recommended 
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -s 172.20.1.0/24 -j TCPMSS  --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```